# Why is a number casted automatically to double?

Tags: java, android, json, casting

I use spring boot for my webservice. Each method returns `Map<Object, Object>` because it is a general type and the methods are able to return any response, either a primitive `int` or complex custom object of `User`. Also I used `Map<Object, Object>` to eliminate backslash "\" in JSON, instead of using String.

But I got problem with variable casting in client (Android app).

Number variables in Map are automatically casted to double (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, ...) while it is `long` in server.

If I cast number to string at server, then casting at client is right e.g. 1, 2, 3, 5, ...

```
return String.valueOf(u.getId())
```

Server side variable:

```
long id;
```

Server side method:

```
public final static String SUCCESS = "0";
public final static String NOT_FOUND = "-1";

Map<Object, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

@RequestMapping("/getUser")
Map<Object, Object> getUser(@RequestParam(value = "phoneNumber", defaultValue = "") String phoneNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "hash", defaultValue = "") String hash) {

    m.clear();

    User user = userRepository.findByPhoneNumberAndHash(phoneNumber, hash);
    if (user != null) {
        m.put(ERROR_JSON, SUCCESS);
        m.put(VALUE_JSON, user);
    } else {
        m.put(ERROR_JSON, NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return m;
}
```

JSON:

```
[{"id":1}] and [{"id":"1"}]
```

Android code. Retrofit

```
userService.getUser(phoneNumber, hash).enqueue(new Callback<Map<Object, Object>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Map<Object, Object>> call, Response<Map<Object, Object>> response) {
        Map<Object, Object> m = response.body();
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Map<Object, Object>> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample JSON and point out the code where you're parsing those values.

Comment: @Sufian this code generates Json.

Comment: The JSON you posted is generated by server or your Android app? And where do you have the problem: on server or Android app?

Comment: The JSON format does not distinghuish between int, long, double; all are number. Use `.longValue()` or something to turn the double into a long.

Comment: @Sufian Json is generated by server. The problem I've got at Android app .But it is possible to resolve it by changing types of variables in POJO class to String. So that android app's code showed above would return right types.

Comment: @JoopEggen I guess the problem is in java type-casting priorities. But Im not sure

Comment: I will show picture

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a JavaScript Object.  In javascript, there are no longs or floats or doubles.  Everything is a number, and it all uses double in the background.  So when you send JSON, unless you tell it to interpret a value as a long explicitly, it has to assume it could be any valid number-  it has to assume its a double.

Comment: if I do request in browser, numbers are shows without floating point

Comment: That means nothing.  JSON is only doubles, so the parser has to assume that a number is a double UNLESS you tell it for sure that it isn't.  So it parses it as a double.  If you want it to be a long, use a prasing method that allows you to tell it what every value's type is.

Comment: Not having a decimal point doesn't mean a number isn't floating point.  It just means it isn't formatted with a decimal.  1 is a perfectly valid floating point number.